# How to extract string resource from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I'm making an application for manage system file extensions, I have a problem.

System extensions like `.jpg`, `.exe`, `.dll`, `.png`, `.txt`, etc. has a registry value called `FriendlyTypeName`, for example, the `FriendlyTypeName` of a jpeg file is `@%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,-30596`. The displayed value depends of the current language.

How to extract the string value from resource id (e.g.: `-30596`) using C#?. I guess strings can be extracted using p/invoke (i'm not sure).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resources can be extract using `LoadString`, `LoadIcon` and etc. However, the `hInstance` must be different of your application's `hInstance`, otherwise, you will only be able to extract resources from your own `.exe`. If you want to extract any resources from external DLLs like system libraries, you must get the `hInstance` of the DLL you want to extract by calling `LoadLibrary`, and call `FreeLibrary` to finish file usage.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, int ID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

private string ExtractStringFromDLL(string file, int number) {
    IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(file);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(2048);
    LoadString(lib, number, result, result.Capacity);
    FreeLibrary(lib);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

`StringBuilder` max capacity is `2048` (if you wish you can change the value).

Here's an example:

```
string loadedString = ExtractStringFromDLL("shell32.dll", 30596);
Debug.Write(loadedString);
```

Windows' default relative path is `%SystemRoot%\system32` and there's not need to include the full path unless you're extracting the string from non-system DLLs.

Don't forget to delete the `-` symbol from resource number because negative numbers means resource ID for `FriendlyTypeName` and `LoadString` requires positive numbers as resource ID.

**EDIT**: You can also extract resources from `.exe` files and any file that contains resources.

Comment: Don't use `LoadLibrary` for resource access, instead `LoadLibraryEx(filename, null, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE)`

Comment: ..and also specifying LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE