# How to use PowerShell to extract data from .dll or .exe files

Tags: windows, powershell, extract, powershell-5.0

I want to list all the services whose startup type is set to automatic

I'm using PowerShell 5

```
$path = 'hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services'
$services = get-childitem $path | get-itemproperty -name 'Start'
foreach ($s in $services){
    if($s.'Start' -like '2'){
        $dn = get-itemproperty $s.'pspath' -name 'DisplayName'
        echo $dn
    }
}
```

But problem is most of the entries are using something like this:

```
@%systemroot%\system32\SearchIndexer.exe,-103
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wscsvc.dll,-200
```

So how to extract string from it?

To clarify a little bit further, for `@%systemroot%\system32\SearchIndexer.exe,-103` the Display Name is `"Windows Search"`. The question is, is PowerShell capable of extract string `"Windows Search"` out of `SearchIndexer.exe`? And how to do that?

**UPDATE:**

Basically stole the code from [How to extract string resource from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968416/how-to-extract-string-resource-from-dll)

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class ExtractData
{
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, int ID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

public string ExtractStringFromDLL(string file, int number) {
    IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(file);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(2048);
    LoadString(lib, number, result, result.Capacity);
    FreeLibrary(lib);
    return result.ToString();
}
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

$ed = New-Object ExtractData

$path = 'hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services'
$services = get-childitem $path | get-itemproperty -name 'Start' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
foreach ($s in $services){
    if($s.'Start' -like '2'){
        $dn = get-itemproperty $s.'pspath' -name 'DisplayName'
        try{
        $dn = $dn.DisplayName.Split(',')
        $dn = $ed.ExtractStringFromDLL([Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($dn[0]).substring(1), $dn[1].substring(1))
        }
        catch{}
        finally{
        echo $dn
        }
    }
}
```

Ugly, but it worked, finally......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
get-service | where-object StartType -eq Automatic
```

?

Comment: Thx! That's a lot better way to do it. But can I still get the answer to how to extract string from .dll, .exe files? Just curious

Comment: @oNion: I was thinking about that. I don't think you can depend on either there always being a resource ID appended or the path name not containing a comma! So may need to apply a few heuristics for a robust solution. But the easy case is (string in `$s`)  `[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($s.Substring(1, $s.LastIndexOf(',')-1))`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it made `@%SystemRoot%\System32\wscsvc.dll,-200` become `@%SystemRoot%\System32\wscsvc.dll`, not exactly extract data in the file. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @oNion In the Q you have "extract the string" which I read as filename. If you need data from inside the file that gets complicated quickly (you'll need to call Win32 resource APIs). And in many cases it will be a just a string (there is no requirement for the display name to be a resource reference).

Comment: @oNion: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968416/how-to-extract-string-resource-from-dll) the C# code could be wrapped into a class and then loaded dynamically via `Add-Type -TypeDefinition $codeString`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It works in PowerShell 3, so should also in higher versions.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | 
    Where-Object StartMode -eq Auto | 
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any way to extract data from .exe and .dll files? Just curious

Comment: I'd bet good money that the answer is here on SO, and not too hard to find.

Comment: Maybe look at using `get-content -encoding byte`.